# Running script using local Python and packages but executing certain commands on remote server

Tags: python, ssh, hive, pyspark

I know how to run a Python script made locally on a remote server and have seen a lot of questions in that regard. But I am in a situation where I cannot install python packages on the remote server I am accessing. Specifically, I need to use pypostal, which requires libpostal to be installed and I cannot do so. Moreover, I need pyspark to play with Hive tables.

Therefore, I need the script to run locally, where I can manage my packages and everything executes fine, but certain commands need to access the server in order to grab data. For example, using pyspark to get Hive tables on the server into a local dataframe. Essentially, I need all the Python to be executed using my local distribution with my local packages but perform its actions on the remote server.

I have looked into things like paramiko. But as far as I can workout, is just like an SSH client, which would use the Python distro on the remote server and not locally. Though, perhaps I don't understand how to use it properly.

I am running python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 using WSL. The packages I am using are pandas, numpy, pyspark, and postal (subsequently libpostal).

TLDR;

Is it possible to run a script locally, have parts of it execute remotely but using my local Python? Or if there are other possible solutions, I would be grateful.

Comment: We have a similar problem and have looked at turning libpostal into a gRPC service you can call from Python locally. You would just have to scale the requests to handle large datasets, not the processing. I'll update with an answer when we open source this contribution.